# Need MySQL query to return result with array using of group by cause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables child and parent

child table

```
Id data parent_id
----------------------
1      a1       1
2      abc      2
3      abcd     1
4      xyz      1
5      zxyy     2
```

parent table

```
Id     data
----------------
1      p1
2      p2
```

Using single MySql query I want output like

```
parentID   parentData    childData
--------------------------------------
1          p1            a1
                         abcd
                         xyz
2          p2            abc
                         zxyy

-------------------------------------
```

I am using PHP if that matters to anyone.

### EDIT

Can anyone help me here ... [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05126/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this-

```
Select parent.id,parent.data,child.data from parent
  LEFT JOIN child ON parent.id = child.parent_id
```

Alternatively you can also do like below (if you want all data should be in a single row)

```
Select parent.id,parent.data,group_concat(child.data SEPARATOR ' ') as cdata from parent
  LEFT JOIN child ON  parent.id = child.parent_id group by parent_id
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. please check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05126/4 I have try here but not working can you suggest

Comment: Sorry Raidon, It was my bad.  you can do like this  "Select website.id,website.website_url,url_list.url
  from website
  LEFT JOIN url_list ON website.id = url_list.website_id"

Comment: Thanks its working..... but 
is possible to get links in array because I don't want to repeat website_url. I want to display it in one record not 3 record. is this possible?

Comment: You can do it with group_concat check my second query.like  "Select website.id,website.website_url, 
  group_concat(url_list.url SEPARATOR ',') as cdata
  from website
  LEFT JOIN url_list on  website.id = url_list.website_id
  group by website.id"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pt.id,pt.data,ct.data FROM parent_table pt 
LEFT JOIN child_table ct 
ON pt.ID = ct.parent_id 
GROUP BY ct.data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.parent_id, p.data, c.data
FROM parents p INNER JOIN childs c ON p.id = c.parent_id
ORDER BY p.parend_id ASC, p.data ASC, c.data ASC
```